# Angular API: headers being set in lazyUpdate

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I am making an API call from angular - and it is putting the headers into lazyUpdates.

[image]

This is the code making the call:

```
        private sendRequest<T>(verb: string, url: string, body?: T): Observable<T> {
          let myHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
          myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Access-Key", "<secret>");
          myHeaders = myHeaders.set("InstallationID", "0001");
          myHeaders = myHeaders.set("FromLocal", "true");
          myHeaders = myHeaders.set("Application-Names", ["exampleApp", "proAngular"]);

          return this.http.request<T>(verb, url, {
            body: body,
            headers: myHeaders
          }).pipe(catchError((error: Response) =>
          throwError(`Network Error: ${error.statusText} (${error.status})`)));
        }
```

The signature of the API method receiving the call is

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("CommitAll")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CommitAll([FromBody] string updateDetailsStr)
        {
         ...
        }
```

The receiving API is C# .NET Core and it cannot see the values. I need to be either force them into myHeaders.headers or read them from myheaders.lazyUpdate. How do I do this?

Comment: And what's the signature of the API method who is receiving the call?

Comment: I've edited the original question to include that now

Answer (score 0):

Headers is a collection inside the Request object. You need to access it how you would access a member from a collection.
Try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
var nameFilter= string.Empty;
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("lazyUpdate", out headerValues))
{
    nameFilter = headerValues.FirstOrDefault(); //<-- Or something
}
```

Comment: Thanks @J.Salas. The day job has taken over for now. I will try this when I pick this task up again.

Comment: No, that did not work. The answer was even easier. The keys are being converted to lowercase - so "InstallationID" in the angular header becomes "installationid" on the request. I can retrieve it with something like nt16.TryParse(context.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "installationid").Value.ToString(), out this.transmittingInstallationID);